# Jasmine: When a test return SPEC HAS NOT EXPECTATION?

Tags: angular, jasmine

i have this test that returns "SPEC HAS NOT EXPECTATION" without fails, do you have any idea? maybe i am not following the best practice;

```
 editComponent has been declared into the Test.bed  into the declaration[]

it('test', fakeAsync(() => {
        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
            editComponent = component.editComponent;
            editComponent.ruleForm = new FormGroup({
                title: new FormControl('test field'),
                cause: new FormControl('test field'),
            });
            fixture.detectChanges();
            spyOn(ruleEditComponent, 'updateRule').withArgs(activeIssueId);
            component.saveRuleDetails(activeIssueId);
            expect(editComponent.createRule).toHaveBeenCalledWith(activeIssueId);
        });

    }));
```

When a test return SPEC HAS NOT EXPECTATION?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fixture.whenStable` returns a `Promise` and it's result is handled asynchronously. Therefore the unit test ends even before any `expect` is invoked.

`fakeAsync` must be used together with `tick` or `flush` in order to simulate asynchronous processing in a synchronous way. Try to rewrite your test as follows.

```
it('test', fakeAsync(() => {
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        editComponent = component.editComponent;
        editComponent.ruleForm = new FormGroup({
            title: new FormControl('test field'),
            cause: new FormControl('test field'),
        });
        fixture.detectChanges();
        spyOn(ruleEditComponent, 'updateRule').withArgs(activeIssueId);
        component.saveRuleDetails(activeIssueId);        
    });
    tick();
    expect(editComponent.createRule).toHaveBeenCalledWith(activeIssueId);
}));
```

Alternatively you can use the `done` function as follows.

```
it('test', (done) => {
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        editComponent = component.editComponent;
        editComponent.ruleForm = new FormGroup({
            title: new FormControl('test field'),
            cause: new FormControl('test field'),
        });
        fixture.detectChanges();
        spyOn(ruleEditComponent, 'updateRule').withArgs(activeIssueId);
        component.saveRuleDetails(activeIssueId);        
        expect(editComponent.createRule).toHaveBeenCalledWith(activeIssueId);
        done();
    });        
}));
```